# singular or plural "start and finish time" or "start and finish times"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

(1) What is the start and finish time of your first class?

(2) What are the start and finish time of your first class?

(3) What are the start and finish time**S** of your first class?

I am not sure which one is correct. Thanks.

Comment: You are asking for two distinct times, so why would (3) not be correct?

Comment: To @KateBunting’s precisely on-topic question, I’d add the general pointer that when one is wrestling with how to optimize a phrase, one should always remember that there is an alternative to striving to optimize it: just replace it. Here, for instance, one could go instead with something in the family of ***When does** your first class…*

Answer (score 1):

Both #2 and #3 are fine, with #3 the more common one.  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=start+and+finish+time%2Cstart+and+finish+times%2Cstart+time+and+finish+time&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

I have included the unelided version, with **start time and finish time**.  This is the least used of the three.

#1 is incorrect.  We have two distinct times, as @Kate Bunting commented, and hence need the plural verb *are*.

Answer (score 0):

#3 is the correct statement. There are two times: a start time and a finish time. That means time is plural:

> What are the start and finish times of your first class?

#1 is probably fairly common in informal spoken English, although technically it's not correct.

#2 is incorrect.